# LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 Redirect URL

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, redirect

I'm attempting to sign in users with the LinkedIn Omniauth 2 gem. I have tried a few different possibilities for the redirect, read several articles and nothing is working.

I'm trying to test this locally.
Rails 4 app

Gems include:
omniauth
omniauth-linkedin-oath2

A few attempts of the redirect URL to put in the box includ:

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=759dczzx23nyic&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Flinkedin%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress&state=8da572e31a8e66e6b1de54acddd14937d976ed06d7ed3217&client_id=*

- = API Key that needs to stay private

  ```
  http://localhost:3000

  http://localhost:3000/

  http://www.localhost:3000

  https://localhost:3000

  https://localhost:3000/

  https://www.localhost:3000
  ```

I read both of these articles the entire way through, but still couldn't attempt to find the correct way to redirect it.

https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/register-your-oauth-2-redirect-urls

https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/oauth-20-redirect-url-faq-invalid-redirecturi-error

Any help in what I need to change would be great.

Answer (score 8):

They need to match exactly what you are sending:

`http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback`

Comment: Hey there is quick question, @Eugenio Pace Can a public IP address be used as LinkedIn `OAuth` redirect URI?

Comment: Very likely (and easy to test). An important aspect of any OAuth2 Authorization Server is that *all* communications are initiated either from:
(1) The user's browser, (2) Your app (the "client" in OAuth2 terminology)
So it doesn't really matter if you use your own */etc/hosts* file with an IP address. As long as your browser or the code running your app can reach LinkedIN (in the example), you will be fine. 
LinkedIN *never* connects with your app.

Answer (score 2):

In case of Linkedin Authorized Redirect URLs should be in form of:

1. http://localhost:8080/your-project-name/auth/linkedin

After authentication if you want to redirect to a specific page then

2. http://localhost:8080/your-project-name/that-page-url

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and kept getting "Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key." error when using Auth0

I added URL below to LinkedIn's list of allowed callback then it worked.

```
https://"Insert your Client Domain Name from Auth0"/login/callback
```