# After Linkedin authentif. redirecting user back to app

Tags: android, url, callback, linkedin-api

I want to allow my customers to log on my smartphone app using Linkedin authentification. And they should be redirected back to the app after entering their name and email.

I make an Android application using Embarcadero Rad Studio , Delphi and I just want to propose to login trough Linkedin ( OAuth process). I have created my application on the linkedin website. I have my client ID and secret ID and all is fine. But I do not understand which URL I have to put on the linkedin page (and in my app). Because I want that Linkedin redirets to my smartphone application and not to any website ( so I do not have any http///url to put ...)

If someone could help me it will be very very appreciated. :)

Comment: What is your goal ? Are you building an Android application ? 
Do you want to use LinkedIn for Authentication ? Do you want to extend your Android application so that your users can log into your Android application by using their Linkedin credentials ?

Comment: Hello, thank's to answer on Sunday ! :) Yes I make an Android application using Embarcadero Rad Studio , Delphi and I just want to propose to login trough  Linkedin  ( OAuth process). I have create my application on the linkedin website   I have my client ID and secret ID all is fine  but  I do not understand which URL I have to put on the linkedin page (and in my app). Because I want thant Linkedin re diret on my smartphone application and not on any website ( so I do not have any http///url to put ...) :(

Comment: You're welcome ! Please update your question, so that we can understand what your goal is.

Comment: I have made a smartphone Android application using Embarcadero Rad Studio Delphi and I want to propose to login to my application trough Linkedin OAuth2 process and get back user id and email. 
I have created my application on the linkedin website, I have my client ID and secret ID all is fine but I do not understand which URL I have to put on the linkedin page (and in my app). I do not want that Linkdedin re direct on any http:// website  but on the mobile application  I have made

Answer (score 0):

RedirectURI can be localhost along with port number specified so that within app you run ServerSocket bind to local host + specified port waiting to accept the connection to receive oauth token. 
Once the token is received by ServerSocket then connection can be closed.

Note that URI should exactly match as to where you are binding serversocket.
This has been further clarified in: [LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 Redirect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105135/linkedin-oauth-2-0-redirect-url)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your answer. I have also read the link you suggered but unfortunatly I have tried unsucessfully to put the localhost url you suggered
I need a call back url for an Android app
Here what I have put in my code and on the LinkedIn registration page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMmkY.jpg)